# Want to store "char values" in array (in C language)

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I want to store "char data type values" in an array, but it doesn't work.

First, I tried using "gets"
but it gave me a run time error.
Code was like this

```
   int tmp = 0;


   char arr[100] = { 0, };
   while (arr[tmp]!=NULL)
   {
      gets(arr[tmp]);
      tmp++;
   }
   for (int rtmp = 0; rtmp < a; rtmp++)
    printf("%s ", arr[rtmp]);
   return 0;
```

In a second way, I was using "scanf", but I couldn't store "char data type(it should be more than one character like string)", but only one character was available.(I tried %s, but it doesn't work)
Plus, it doesn't print the last value of array.

```
int a = 0;
scanf("%d", &a); //determine how much I input values

int tmp = 0;
char arr[100] ={ 0 , };
for(tmp=0;tmp<a;tmp++)
{
    scanf("%c ",arr[tmp]);
    fflush(stdin);
}
for (int rtmp = 0; rtmp < a; rtmp++)
    printf("%c ", arr[rtmp]);
return 0;
```

The most "identical" for me is
without notifying "a" values("a" means how much values I input)
and storing "char values" in array..

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance! Your help is always appreciated :)

Comment: `scanf("%c ",arr[tmp]);` --> `scanf("%c", &arr[tmp]);`

Comment: In the first case, you have an array of `char`, but you try to treat the *elements* as (pointers to) `char` arrays.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour. You cannot flush input streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array of char data type is called Sting. You can take a string's input using scanf() and gets(). But if you use scanf(), the string will be input by pressing Space-bar or Enter. But if you use gets(), input will be given only by pressing the Enter key.

Example 1:

```
char s[100];
scanf("%s", s);
```

Example 2:

```
char s[100];
gets(s);
```

Now, if you want to input every single character individually, you can do that also:

```
    char s[100], c;
    int n, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &s[i]);
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
```

Now look, I wrote a `getchar()` after `scanf("%d", &n);`, because when you press enter after inputting n, a new line character ('\n') is also taken as input in the character next to n. So you must do this in case like this.

One more thing, you can take input any string containing spaces using `scanf()` also. Just do this:

```
char s[100];
scanf("%[^\n]", s);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can not enter the individual character by following snippet of code.

```
    char arr[10] = {0};
    //unsigned char ch;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    printf("Enter the array elements\n");
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
            scanf("%c", &arr[i]);
            printf("i = %d and arr[%d] = %c\n", i, i, arr[i]);
    }
```

The result of this snippet is as per this image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRn0R.png)

To avoid this issue, it is recommended to enter the character without new line charactoer '\n' or without pressing enter.

Or other method is to use the array as string and input the character by gets() like this snippet.

```
char s[100];
gets(s);
```

Comment: Pleas do not post images of code or of text output. Provide the text as text instead, please.

Comment: There is no function `gets` in C any more, it was removed as inherently unsafe. Use fgets instead.